# Open Select File Dialog on a predifined directory

Tags: javascript, jquery

For my project I need the users to be able to select a file from his PC.
Every user has his own path, and I must open the Select File Dialog ( Input type="file" ) on his path by default, so they can dirrectly pick the file without the need to search for the directory. By default when you open the Select File Dialog, it opens on a default location , example, Desktop / Downloads, and the next time you open it, on the last time you selected an item.

My question is, how can I archive this?
How can i specify the default Path?
It dosnt matter if you open the page from a Mac or Phone or whatever.
It dosnt need to be a html Input, it could be in JS, JQuery ...

I read that by security reasons you can't, and it seems legit but i found like for mozilla you can https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Open_and_Save_Dialogs

Dunno if this could be archived on other navigators as Chrome or IE.

If anyone has archived it, could you pass me some URLs or code plz?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. it's against the rules. Your "firefox" link refers to extensions, not pages. It would be a security issue to allow scripts to get any information about your computer's directory structure. If the open had an error callback for example, a script could guess user names in the background and try to open a folder for each of them until it no longer failed.

Comment: Isnt't there a way to do it? like a plugin / extension or to let a directory be accessed by Chrome?